# Binary open file in c++/cli or c#

Tags: c++-cli

I have problem with Binary open file in c++/cli. How to open the whole file and save the contest of the file to the array ^.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please make your question more specific and provide what you've done so far or what part you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical method for reading the *contest* [sic] of a *Binarny* [sic] file is to:
1. Determine the length of the file.
2. Allocate dynamic memory for the file.
3. Block read the file, in binary mode, into memory.

Some operating systems may have a *memory map* capability.  This allows a file to be treated as an array.  The OS is in charge of reading the file into memory.  It may read the entire file, or it may read *pages* as necessary (on demand).

See `std::ifstream::read`, `std::ifstream::seekg` and `std::ifstream::tellg`.